# Accidently sent BTC to taproot wallet on Phantom. Wondering how i can get it back to Segwit so i can buy ordinals with it

Tags: segregated-witness, taproot

Hey Guys i sent BTC to my Phantom Taproot account, but now i realize i should have sent it to my segwit acccount. Im wondering how i can transfer it over and if its even possible on Phantom. It was 0.2 BTC so i really hope its not a lost cause.

this is my account -  bc1pyq2d92jd-j2z5cf50w52mw97a-jgdvmkdvu687ec4h-m46kn64pteuqxl4xfk

this is the hash - 5ce798acd74293c708d7d425e93717e903d-ce6c3989d07c81c0ee9110ab06f38

Answer (score 3):

Note that addresses are not accounts.

The only way to move your coins to a different address (regardless of type) is to make a transaction. Presumably the wallet you are using allows you to send Bitcoin, and presumably you are able to retrieve an address of your desired type in your target wallet. So just make a transaction sending to that address from the wallet that has your taproot address.